# Javascript code returning undefined:Nan in the execution output?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to javascript and trying to learn some basics. So I wrote a small script for file reading. Below is my code.

```
// Load the fs (filesystem) module
var fs=require('fs');

// Read the contents of the file into memory.
fs.readFile('example.txt', function (err, logData) {
  // If an error occurred, throwing it will
    //display the exception and end our app.
  if(err) throw err;
  // logData is a Buffer, convert to string.
  var text = logData.toString();

  var results = {};
  var lines = text.split('\n');
  lines.forEach(function(line){
    var parts = line.split(' ');
    var letter = parts[1];
    var count = parseInt(parts[2]);

    if (!results[letter]){
      results[letter] = 0;
    }
    results[letter] +=parseInt(count);
    });
  console.log(results);
});
```

my input file is

```
2013-08-09T13:50:33.166Z A 2
2013-08-09T13:51:33.166Z B 1
2013-08-09T13:52:33.166Z C 6
2013-08-09T13:53:33.166Z B 8
2013-08-09T13:54:33.166Z B 5
```

Number of lines in *example.txt* is 5

```
wc -l example.txt 
5 example.txt
```

Executing the above code using Node.js results in

```
node my_parser.js 
[ '2013-08-09T13:50:33.166Z A 2',
  '2013-08-09T13:51:33.166Z B 1',
  '2013-08-09T13:52:33.166Z C 6',
  '2013-08-09T13:53:33.166Z B 8',
  '2013-08-09T13:54:33.166Z B 5',
  '' ]
{ A: 2, B: 14, C: 6, undefined: NaN }
```

When there are only five lines in the *example.txt* file? Why is an extra empty string added to the list? Is this expected from `split` function? Please help

Comment: did you try to debug?

Comment: Well, `letter` must be `undefined` at some point and `parseInt(count)` return `NaN`. I guess at the end of the last line is also a line break. First step to debug the problem would be to have a look at the content of `lines`.

Comment: I tried debugging but invain. Do you have any pointers on debugging this code ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a `\n` at the end of your data, so the last `line` in that array is empty.

Comment: `var lines = text.split('\n'); console.log(lines);`. You debug code by inspect the values you get and compare them to the values you expect. Then you follow the code backwards to find out how the value was created and either fix code or deal with the different value (e.g. because your expectation was wrong).

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling for helping in the initial investigation. I have edited my question with the new findings. please take a look.

Answer (score 4):

Does the file have a new-line character at the end? If so the last array item will be an empty string